# Would a small scratch/puncture on a lithium battery cause power drain?

Tags: lithium-ion

I replaced my phone screen myself and afterwards noticed the battery life was significantly worse.

I scratched the battery slightly getting it out as it was firmly glued in.

Would slightly bending the battery while prising it out or this superficial scratch cause reduced battery life? I am trying to rule out whether it's the battery or something else to justify replacing it.

I've recharged the phone many times since then, and the battery lasts (according to monitoring software) for around 12 hours, whereas before it would last for around 4 days. I put electrical tape over the damage yesterday to see if it would help.

[image: Photo of battery]

Comment: This is not a scratch, it is a puncture.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure where the protective cover ended and the actual battery began. I've updated the title.

Comment: If it's a puncture then it is possible some electrolyte fluid escaped / evaporated which will lower the capacity of the battery. Anyway, I would just **replace the battery**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxygen will leak in and slowly destroy the battery. A larger puncture could have cause a fire.
Please dispose of the battery.

Comment: Thanks, I have ordered a replacement. It seemed superficial until I uploaded the high res image and zoomed in...